# ASP.NET MVC Nullable Datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok, I have a Client object which has a nullable datetime property for "DateOfBirth"
So from the UI, we dont mind if the dateofbirth is not entered, however the issue im having is when displaying that future client, I want to format the datetime like so

```
@client.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

but the issue is that it may return null (from which I dont want to display anything), how do I handle this issue from the UI?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if it's null before displaying it:

```
@if(client.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
{
    @client.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
}
```

Comment: Once you are in a code block, you do not _need_ the second 'at-sign' (that is, @client.Date...). See [C# Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/).

Answer (score 1):

Check for null before calling ToString:

```
@(client.DateOfBirth != null ? client.DateOfBirth.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") : "Not Selected")
```

You can also wrap this in a static class for code re-use:

```
public static class Utils {
    public static string FriendlyDate(DateTime? value) {
        if(value == null) return "Not Selected";
        return value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    }
}
```

And in your View:

```
@Utils.FriendlyDate(client.DateOfBirth)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to expose the date (in my case, date of birth) as a string via the view model and use `.AsDateTime()` to cast it back to a `DateTime`.

```
private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date of birth. ")]
public String DateOfBirth {
    get { return (_dateOfBirth.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.MinValue.ToShortDateString()) ? null : _dateOfBirth.ToShortDateString(); }
    set { _dateOfBirth = value.AsDateTime(); }
}
```